# Systemd Zookeeper service failed

Tags: linux, service, systemd, system-services

I've created the following systemd service script for running Zookeeper using Ansible:

```
[Unit]
Description=ZooKeeper

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
User=zookeeper
Group=zookeeper
ExecStart=/tmp/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh start
ExecStop=/tmp/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh stop

TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But, while trying to run the script using `sudo service zookeeper start` I get the following error:

```
Nov 15 22:00:35 sharedservicesprovider systemd[1]: Starting ZooKeeper...
-- Subject: Unit zookeeper.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit zookeeper.service has begun starting up.
Nov 15 22:00:35 sharedservicesprovider systemd[15287]: zookeeper.service: Failed at step USER spawning /tmp/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh: No such process
-- Subject: Process /tmp/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The process /tmp/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is 3.
Nov 15 22:00:35 sharedservicesprovider systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=217
Nov 15 22:00:35 sharedservicesprovider systemd[1]: Failed to start ZooKeeper.
-- Subject: Unit zookeeper.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

Any hint onto why I am unable to start Zookeeper properly since I'm quite new to system services?

Comment: I am wondering systemsd will take a parameter like `start` after `.sh` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe so late... but use as ExecStart:

/tmp/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground

Answer (score 1):

```
[Unit]
Description=Zookeeper
After=syslog.target
[Service]
Environment=ZOO_LOG_DIR=/zookeeper/logs
SyslogIdentifier=zookeeper
TimoutStartSec=10min
Type=forking
User=zookeeper
Group=zookeeper
ExecStart=/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
ExecStop=/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh stop
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

ZOO_LOG_DIR is for permission require

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like basics to check to me
first, make sure the file exists

```
ls -ltrah /tmp/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh
```

if it doesn't find where you extracted the zookeeper startup script. On my instance, it's `/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh`

Then verify that the user you have specified (you've specified two users, `root` and `zookeeper`. I'm assuming the last value is what's valid/desired) can access the script and has executable rights to it.

This would be done with `chown` and `chmod` commands, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, but for me there were no error messages anywhere stating any cause of failure. The issue was related to a recent change that I made in the `zoo.cfg` file.

#### Issue

There was an extra space after the server URL which was not visible to the naked eye but I noticed that the Vim cursor was going 1 extra character.

`server.1:vmname.domain.com:2888:3888`

> Notice the extra space at the end.

There were no errors in the log about the incorrect server name, but after removing the space my Zookeeper service started.

`systemctl restart zookeeper.service`